# Combine two different probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, percentage

I'm not sure how to best phrase this, but I'm not sure how to combine two probabilities (or if that even makes sense).

Example:

Assume that 5% percent of the population has a particular gene is 20 times more likely to become a professional athlete than those without. Considering all athletes, what percentage of them has this gene?

It seems like the percentage of athletes would be greater than 5%, but I'm not sure how to figure this out. Is this something that can be determined?

---

*Note:* This seems super simple, so it might have already been asked. I searched a lot, but I don't have the right language for this field yet.

Comment: bayes' theorem and the law of total probability together is sufficient to solve this

Comment: Thanks @shimao, I wrote up an answer using those two. I think it makes sense. Can you look it over for correctness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per suggestion of [shimao](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/26948/shimao), the answer lies in the [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Let $G$ be the event that someone has the gene and let $A$ be the event that someone becomes a professional athlete. From the example we know:

$$
P(G) = 0.05 \\
P(G^\prime) = 0.95 \\
P(A|G)/P(A|G^\prime) = 20
$$

What we want to know is what $P(G|A)$. Enter Bayes Theorem

$$
P(G|A) = \frac{P(A|G)P(G)}{P(A)}
$$

Which has two unknowns $P(A|G)$ and $P(A)$, using the Law of Total probability we can find $P(A)$.

$$
P(A) = P(G)P(A|G) + P(A|G^\prime)P(G^\prime)
$$

From $P(A|G)/P(A|G^\prime) = 20$ we can get $P(A|G^\prime) = P(A|G)/20$
and can substitute in to get:

$$
P(A) = P(G)P(A|G) + \frac{P(A|G)P(G^\prime)}{20}
$$

Returning to our application of Bayes Theorem and substituting in this expression of $P(A)$ we get:

$$
P(G|A) = \frac{20\cdot P(A|G)P(G)}{P(A|G)(20 \cdot P(G) + P(G^\prime))}
$$

Which simplifies to 
$$
P(G|A) = \frac{20 \cdot P(G)}{20 \cdot P(G) + P(G^\prime)}
$$

all are known, so 
$$
P(G|A) = \frac{20 \cdot 0.05}{20 \cdot 0.05 + 0.95} \approx 0.51
$$

So the percentage of professional athletes that have this gene is 51%.

Comment: You're missing an extra 20 in your denominator after combining the two. $$P(G|A) = \frac{20P(A|G)P(G)}{P(A|G)(20P(G) + P(G^\prime))}$$

Comment: @dankernler Fixed, thank you for pointing this out :)

Comment: No problem. I haven't done one like this in a while, but the answer of 1 was a red flag!